# How to skip a task in airflow without skipping its downstream tasks?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

Let’s say this is my dag:
A >> B >> C

If task B raises an exception, I want to skip the task instead of failing it. However, I don’t want to skip task C. I looked into AirflowSkipException and the soft_fail sensor but they both forcibly skip downstream tasks as well. Does anyone have a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Currently posted answers touch on different topic or does not seem to be fully correct.

Adding trigger rule `all_failed` to Task-C won't work for OP's example DAG:  `A >> B >> C` unless Task-A ends in `failed` state, which most probably is not desirable.

OP was, in fact, very close because expected behavior can be achieved with mix of `AirflowSkipException` and `none_failed` trigger rule:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.exceptions import AirflowSkipException
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="mydag",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 18),
    schedule_interval="@once"
) as dag:

    def task_b():
        raise AirflowSkipException

    A = DummyOperator(task_id="A")
    B = PythonOperator(task_id="B", python_callable=task_b)
    C = DummyOperator(task_id="C", trigger_rule="none_failed")

    A >> B >> C
```

which Airflow executes as follows:

[image]

What this rule mean?

> **Trigger Rules**
>
> **none_failed:** All upstream tasks have not failed or upstream_failed -
> that is, all upstream tasks have succeeded or been skipped

So basically we can catch the actual exception in our code and raise mentioned Airflow exception which "*force*" task state change from `failed` to `skipped`.
However, without the `trigger_rule` argument to Task-C we would end up with Task-B downstream marked as `skipped`.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the Airflow documentation on [trigger_rule](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules).

`trigger_rule` allows you to configure the task's execution dependency. Generally, a task is executed when all upstream tasks succeed. You can change that to other [trigger rules provided in Airflow](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.14/airflow/utils/trigger_rule.py). The `all_failed` trigger rule only executes a task when all upstream tasks fail, which would accomplish what you outlined.

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

with DAG(
        dag_id="my_dag",
        start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5),
        schedule_interval='@once',
) as dag:
    p = PythonOperator(
        task_id='fail_task',
        python_callable=lambda x: 1,
    ) 
    
    t = PythonOperator(
        task_id='run_task',
        python_callable=lambda: 1,
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_FAILED
    )
    
    p >> t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `trigger_rule` in your task declaration.

```py
task = BashOperator(
    task_id="task_C",
    bash_command="echo hello world",
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: I also think trigger_rule should be set as "all_done".  with "none_failed" if B fails C will not be triggered. A >> B (proceed with "all_done" trigger regardless of exception or fail) >> C. It is not clear if ops wants to run downstream task C in case of upstream task B raise exception or failure.